# Taxonomy term relationships

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have 3 taxonomy terms that I would like to expose as filters but I would like to use JavaScript to disable filters as you make selections in the other related exposed filters. For example:

| Styles | Makes | Models |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cars | BMW | 750i |
| Trucks | Ford | F-150 |

If you select "Cars" then the "Makes - Ford" and "Models - F-150" would be disabled. I currently have each item assigned a proper CSS class for hooks but I am needing to find a way to add a CSS class to each "Makes" item and "Models" item that would be available if the user selected "Styles - Cars".

I need to do this on form field change and without refreshing the page. Is this possible?

Much thanks in advanced.

Comment: You might want to consider one of these modules: https://www.drupal.org/project/cshs or https://www.drupal.org/project/shs

Answer (score 0):

@beltouche, thanks for the module ideas. I ended up going another route because I needed the filters to update as each one changed. Basically, just like a facet but without reloading the page. I'm sure there are a few ways to go about this and probably in a more efficient way but for the amount of items and the functionality I needed this seems to be working pretty good.

For anyone else that is looking to try and accomplish the same, here are the steps I took to accomplish what I needed.

1. I have a content type called "inventory" that hold about 700 entries
2. There are 3 fields in "inventory" that I would like to use to filter by
3. I created a view showing content of type "inventory"
4. Name the view "Custom Quick Search"
5. Check to "create a block"
6. Set the view to "show Fields"
7. Add the 3 fields, style, make, model
8. Set items per page to "all"
9. Create custom view templates:
10. views-view-unformatted--custom-quick-search
11. views-view-fields--custom-quick-search
12. views-view-field--field-style
13. views-view-field--field-make
14. views-view-field--field-model

The code for each are as follows:
**views-view-unformatted--custom-quick-search**

```
{% for row in rows %}
  {% if row|render|trim is not empty %}
    {{ row.content }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**views-view-fields--custom-quick-search**

```
{% set category_name = fields.field_category.content|striptags %}
{% set category_id = fields.field_category.content|preg_replace('(<a href="/taxonomy/term/)','$1') %}
{% set category_id = category_id|preg_replace('(" hreflang="en">.*)','$1') %}

{% set make_name = fields.field_make.content|striptags %}
{% set make_id = fields.field_make.content|preg_replace('(<a href="/taxonomy/term/)','$1') %}
{% set make_id = make_id|preg_replace('(" hreflang="en">.*)','$1') %}

{% set model_name = fields.field_model.content|striptags %}
{% set model_id = fields.field_model.content|preg_replace('(<a href="/taxonomy/term/)','$1') %}
{% set model_id = model_id|preg_replace('(" hreflang="en">.*)','$1') %}

<div class="item" style="display: none;" data-category="{{ category_name|clean_class }}" data-make="{{ make_name|clean_class }}" data-model="{{ model_name|clean_class }}">

  <div class="-styles" data-category="{{ category_name|clean_class }}">
    <label for="{{ category_name|clean_class }}" data-category="{{ category_name|clean_class }}" data-make="{{ make_name|clean_class }}" data-model="{{ model_name|clean_class }}">
      <input type="checkbox" name="{{ category_name|trim }}" value="{{ category_id|trim }}" class="{{ category_name|trim|clean_class }}" id="{{ category_name|trim|clean_class }}" />
    {{ category_name|trim }}</label>
  </div>

  <div class="-makes" data-category="{{ category_name|clean_class }}" data-make="{{ make_name|clean_class }}">
    <label for="{{ make_name|clean_class }}" data-category="{{ category_name|clean_class }}" data-make="{{ make_name|clean_class }}" data-model="{{ model_name|clean_class }}">
      <input type="checkbox" name="{{ make_name|trim }}" value="{{ make_id|trim }}" class="{{ make_name|trim|clean_class }}" id="{{ make_name|trim|clean_class }}" />
    {{ make_name|trim }}</label>
  </div>

  <div class="-models" data-category="{{ category_name|clean_class }}" data-make="{{ make_name|clean_class }}" data-model="{{ model_name|clean_class }}">
    <label for="{{ model_name|clean_class }}" data-category="{{ category_name|clean_class }}" data-make="{{ make_name|clean_class }}" data-model="{{ model_name|clean_class }}">
      <input type="checkbox" name="{{ model_name|trim }}" value="{{ model_id|trim }}" class="{{ model_name|trim|clean_class }}" id="{{ model_name|trim|clean_class }}" />
    {{ model_name|trim }}</label>
  </div>

</div>
```

**views-view-field--field-style
views-view-field--field-make
views-view-field--field-model**

```
{{ output }}
```

---

**Place the block on a page wrapped in the following:**

```
<div class="quickSearch hidden">
    <div class="quickSearch__content">
        <div class="quickSearch__filters">
            <div class="filters-widget -styles">
                <div class="filters-widget__items">
                    <div class="filters-widget__item">
                    <div class="filters-widget__header">
                        <h4>Styles</h4>
                        <i class="fas fa-expand-alt"></i>
                        <i class="far fa-compress-alt"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="filters-widget__copy">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="filters-widget -makes">
                <div class="filters-widget__items">
                    <div class="filters-widget__item">
                    <div class="filters-widget__header">
                        <h4>Makes</h4>
                        <i class="fas fa-expand-alt"></i>
                        <i class="far fa-compress-alt"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="filters-widget__copy">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="filters-widget -models">
                <div class="filters-widget__items">
                    <div class="filters-widget__item">
                    <div class="filters-widget__header">
                        <h4>Models</h4>
                        <i class="fas fa-expand-alt"></i>
                        <i class="far fa-compress-alt"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="filters-widget__copy">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="unsorted__styles" style="display: none;"></div>
            <div class="unsorted__makes" style="display: none;"></div>
            <div class="unsorted__models" style="display: none;"></div>

            <div data-drupal-selector="edit-actions" class="form-actions js-form-wrapper form-wrapper" id="edit-actions">
            <input data-drupal-selector="edit-submit-custom-search-inventory" type="submit" id="edit-submit-custom-search-inventory" value="Search" class="button js-form-submit form-submit -brand-01">
            </div>
            {{ drupal_entity('block', 'views_block__custom_quick_search_block_quick_search', check_access=false) }}
        </div>
        <div class="quickSearch__links">
            {{ drupal_entity('block_content', '8') }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**The rest of the code is the JavaScript that swaps out the fields**

```
/**
     * Clear disabled from makes and models on front page
     * Clone makes into unsorted
     * Remove duplicate entries
     * Reorder into alpha desc and move into dropdown
     */
 function loadMakes(show_styles){
  console.log(show_styles);
  if( show_styles == 'all' ){
    jQuery('.quickSearch .item .-makes').clone().prependTo('.quickSearch .unsorted__makes');
  }
  else{
    jQuery('.quickSearch .item .-makes[data-category="'+show_styles+'"]').clone().prependTo('.quickSearch .unsorted__makes');
  }
  //
  // Remove duplicates from makes dropdown.
  var makes = {};
  jQuery('.unsorted__makes .-makes').each(function() {
    var make = jQuery(this).attr('data-make');
    if (makes[make])
      jQuery(this).remove();
    else
      makes[make] = true;
  });
  // Reorder alpha and move to drop downs.
  jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.unsorted__makes .-makes').sort(sort_makes).clone().prependTo('.filters-widget.-makes .filters-widget__copy');
    function sort_makes(a, b){
      return(jQuery(b).data('make')) < (jQuery(a).data('make')) ? 1 : -1;
    }
  });
}

/**
 *
 * Clone models into unsorted
 * Remove duplicate entries
 * Reorder into alpha desc and move into dropdown
 */
function loadModels(show_styles,show_makes){
  if( show_makes == 'all' ){
    jQuery('.quickSearch .item .-models').clone().prependTo('.quickSearch .unsorted__models');
  }
  else{
    jQuery('.quickSearch .item .-models[data-category="'+show_styles+'"][data-make="'+show_makes+'"]').clone().prependTo('.quickSearch .unsorted__models');
  }
  //
  // Remove duplicates from models dropdown.
  var models = {};
  jQuery('.unsorted__models .-models').each(function() {
    var model = jQuery(this).attr('data-model');
    if (models[model])
      jQuery(this).remove();
    else
      models[model] = true;
  });
  // Reorder alpha and move to drop downs.
  jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.unsorted__models .-models').sort(sort_models).clone().prependTo('.filters-widget.-models .filters-widget__copy');
    function sort_models(a, b){
      return(jQuery(b).data('model')) < (jQuery(a).data('model')) ? 1 : -1;
    }
  });
}

/**
         * Move styles into unsorted
         * Remove empty entries
         * Remove duplicate entries
         * Reorder into alpha desc and move into dropdown
         */
        // Remove empty entries
        jQuery('.quickSearch .item').each(function(){
            if( jQuery(this).data('make') == undefined || jQuery(this).data('make') == null || jQuery(this).data('make') == ''){
                jQuery(this).remove();
            }
        });
        jQuery('.quickSearch .item .-styles').prependTo('.quickSearch .unsorted__styles');
        // Remove duplicates from styles dropdown.
        var styles = {};
        jQuery('.unsorted__styles .-styles').each(function() {
            var style = jQuery(this).attr('data-category');
            if (styles[style])
                jQuery(this).remove();
            else
                styles[style] = true;
        });
        // Reorder alpha and move to drop downs.
        jQuery(function(){
            jQuery('.unsorted__styles .-styles').sort(sort_styles).prependTo('.filters-widget.-styles .filters-widget__copy');
            function sort_styles(a, b){
                return(jQuery(b).data('category')) < (jQuery(a).data('category')) ? 1 : -1;
            }
        });

        // Show and hide makes and models based on selected style
        var show_styles = '';
        jQuery('.-styles input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
            jQuery('.-styles input[type=checkbox]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
            jQuery('.-makes .filters-widget__copy, .-models .filters-widget__copy').html('');
            jQuery('.unsorted__makes, .unsorted__models').html('');
            show_styles = jQuery(this).parent().data('category');
            loadMakes(show_styles);
            loadModels(show_styles,show_styles);
        });

        // Show and hide makes and models based on selected style
        var show_makes = '';
        jQuery('.-makes').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function(){
            jQuery('.-makes input[type=checkbox]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
            jQuery('.-models .filters-widget__copy').html('');
            jQuery('.unsorted__models').html('');
            show_styles = jQuery(this).parent().data('category');
            show_makes = jQuery(this).parent().data('make');
            loadModels(show_styles,show_makes);
        });

        // Quick Search submit button
        jQuery('.quickSearch .form-submit').on('click', function(){
            styles = jQuery('.-styles input:checked').val();
            makes = jQuery('.-makes input:checked').val();
            models = jQuery('.-models input:checked').val();
            var quick_search_url = '';
            if( styles && !makes && !models ){
                quick_search_url = 'category/'+styles;
            }
            else if( styles && makes && !models ){
                quick_search_url = 'category/'+styles;
                quick_search_url += '/make/'+makes;
            }
            else if( styles && !makes && models ){
                quick_search_url = 'category/'+styles;
                quick_search_url += '/model/'+models;
            }
            else if( styles && makes && models ){
                quick_search_url = 'category/'+styles;
                quick_search_url += '/make/'+makes;
                quick_search_url += '/model/'+models;
            }
            else if( !styles && makes && !models ){
                quick_search_url += '/make/'+makes;
            }
            else if( !styles && makes && models ){
                quick_search_url += '/make/'+makes;
                quick_search_url += '/model/'+models;
            }
            else if( !styles && !makes && models ){
                quick_search_url += '/model/'+models;
            }

            window.location.href = '/inventory-search/'+quick_search_url;
        });

        loadMakes('all');
        loadModels('all','all');

    }
```